# Cannot run program after creating virtual environment

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I have copied a python project from Window10(using Pycharm) and tried to run in Ubuntu env(Pycharm again). The project has Flask based API calling.
Everytime I try to run this file to run the entire project in Pycharm I get an error as following

```
Error running 'app_local': Cannot run program "C:/WindowUsers/.conda/envs/venvName/python.exe" (in directory "/home/LinuxUser/projectName"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I have created a virtual environment in Conda and duly activated. I checked Python version too and all are in placed within the virtual env.
I am not able to understand why this file is not running while it ran in past.

The `app_local.py` is the file I try to run, where `api_main` is the Blueprint variable.

```
from Script import api_main
from flask import Flask

mr_app = Flask(__name__)

mr_app.register_blueprint(api_main)
mr_app = Flask(__name__)
mr_app.register_blueprint(api_main)
mr_app.run(host=0.0.0.0, port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Please check `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter` setting

Comment: I checked but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You have set up old paths in project. That is why you have path to "python.exe" somewhere in project (`Cannot run program "C:/WindowUsers/.conda/envs/venvName/python.exe"`).
Go to projects directory and search for it. You will see where it is "hard wired" so you can check it.

```
$ grep -R -inH "python.exe" *
```

It will show you exact location of the "python.exe" path, and start debugging the problem from here.